# php+laravel , quantity get back

Tags: php, html, laravel, oop

I have 3 tables (`sales`, `sales_detail`, and `bicycle`). I don't know how to get back my quantity (`sales`) to unit balance (`bicycle`) and then delete the `sales_detail` entry because I'm going to update new sales.

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id) {

    $sales = Sales::find($id);
    $sales_details = SalesDetail::where('sales_id', $id)->get();
    $bicycles = Bicycle::where('sales_id', $id)->get();
    foreach ($bicycles as $bc && $sales_details as $sd) {
        $bc->unit_balance = $sd->quantity + $bc->unit_balance;
        //then delete sales_detail
    }

    return view('sales/edit', array( 
        'sales' => $sales, 
        'sales_details' => $sales_details, 
        'bicycles' => $bicycles
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
public function edit(Request $request, $id) {

    $sales = Sales::find($id); // get sales where sales_id = 40
    $sales_details = SalesDetail::where('sales_id', $id)->get();

    return view('sales/edit', array( 'sales' => $sales,
    'sales_details' => $sales_details ));
  }

  public function update(Request $request, $id) {

    $sales = Sales::find($id);
    $sales_details = SalesDetail::where('sales_id',$id)->get();

    foreach ($sales_details as $sales_dtl) {
      $bicycle = Bicycle::find($sales_dtl->bicycle_id);
      $bicycle->unit_balance = $bicycle->unit_balance + $sales_dtl['quantity'];
      $bicycle->save();
      $sales_dtl->delete();
    }
    $this->saveData($sales,$request);

    return redirect()->route('sales.index');
  }
```

**i get my answer already**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the use of Elequents relations in your Models such as 'belongsto' and 'hasmany' to better prepare data. Following this practice would allow you to simplify your queries during development. Your approach is very messy/novice and procedural.

Checkout https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships